# Make a momentary highlight inside a virtualized list when render is not triggered

Tags: reactjs, react-virtuoso

I have an extensive list of items in an application, so it is rendered using a virtual list provided by react-virtuoso. The content of the list itself changes based on API calls made by a separate component. What I am trying to achieve is whenever a new item is added to the list, the list automatically scrolls to that item and then highlights it for a second.

What I managed to come up with is to have the other component place the id of the newly created item inside a context that the virtual list has access to. So the virtual list looks something like this:

```js
function MyList(props) {

  const { collection } = props;
  
  const { getLastId } useApiResultsContext();
  
  cosnt highlightIndex = useRef();
  const listRef = useRef(null);
  
  const turnHighlightOff = useCallback(() => {
    highlighIndex.current = undefined;
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = getLastId(); 
    // calling this function also resets the lastId inside the context,
    // so next time it is called it will return undefined
    // unless another item was entered
    
    if (!id) return;
    
    const index = collection.findIndex((item) => item.id === if);
    
    if (index < 0) return;
    
    listRef.current?.scrollToIndex({ index, align: 'start' });
    
    highlightIndex.current = index;
  }, [collection, getLastId]);
  
  return (
    <Virtuoso
      ref={listRef}
      data={collection}
      itemContent={(index, item) => (
        <ItemRow
          content={item}
          toHighlight={highlighIndex.current}
          checkHighlight={turnHighlightOff}
        />
      )}
    />
  ); 
}
```

I'm using `useRef` instead of `useState` here because using a state breaks the whole thing - I guess because Virtuouso doesn't actually re-renders when it scrolls. With `useRef` everything actually works well. Inside `ItemRow` the highlight is managed like this:

```js
function ItemRow(props) {
 const { content, toHighlight, checkHighligh } = props;
 
 const highlightMe = toHighlight;
 
 useEffect(() => {
  toHighlight && checkHighlight && checkHighligh();
 });
 
 return (
  <div className={highlightMe ? 'highligh' : undefined}>
    // ... The rest of the render
  </div>
 );
}
```

In CSS I defined for the `highligh` class a 1sec animation with a change in `background-color`.

Everything so far works exactly as I want it to, except for one issue that I couldn't figure out how to solve: if the list scrolls to a row that was out of frame, the highlight works well because that row gets rendered. However, if the row is already in-frame, react-virtuoso does not need to render it, and so, because I'm using a ref instead of a state, the highlight never gets called into action. As I mentioned above, using `useState` broke the entire thing so I ended up using `useRef`, but I don't know how to force a re-render of the needed row when already in view.

Answer (score 0):

I *kinda* solved this issue. My solution is not the best, and in some rare cases doesn't highlight the row as I want, but it's the best I could come up with unless someone here has a better idea.

The core of the solution is in changing the idea behind the `getLastId` that is exposed by the context. Before it used to reset the id back to `undefined` as soon as it is drawn by the component in `useEffect`. Now, instead, the context exposes two functions - one function to get the id and another to reset it. Basically, it throws the responsibility of resetting it to the component. Behind the scenes, `getLastId` and `resetLastId` manipulate a ref object, not a state in order to prevent unnecessary renders. So, now, `MyList` component looks like this:

```js
function MyList(props) {

  const { collection } = props;
  
  const { getLastId, resetLastId } useApiResultsContext();
  
  cosnt highlightIndex = useRef();
  const listRef = useRef(null);
  
  const turnHighlightOff = useCallback(() => {
    highlighIndex.current = undefined;
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = getLastId();
    resetLastId();
    
    if (!id) return;
    
    const index = collection.findIndex((item) => item.id === if);
    
    if (index < 0) return;
    
    listRef.current?.scrollToIndex({ index, align: 'start' });
    
    highlightIndex.current = index;
  }, [collection, getLastId]);
  
  return (
    <Virtuoso
      ref={listRef}
      data={collection}
      itemContent={(index, item) => (
        <ItemRow
          content={item}
          toHighlight={highlighIndex.current === index || getLastId() === item.id}
          checkHighlight={turnHighlightOff}
        />
      )}
    />
  ); 
}
```

Now, setting the `highlightIndex` inside `useEffect` takes care of items outside the viewport, and feeding the `getLastId` call into the properties of each `ItemRow` takes care of those already in view.